# Huge SOAP response using Spring cxf being truncated

Tags: soap, apache-camel, soap-client, spring-cxf

I was trying to make a SOAP call with the following codes:

```
MessageContentsList response = producerTemplate
  .requestBodyAndHeaders(endpoint, request, headers, MessageContentsList.class);
```

The codes were returning truncated SOAP response. The logs were showing:

```
at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapCamelExecutionException(ObjectHelper.java:1772) ~[camel-core-2.19.0.jar:2.19.0]
at org.apache.camel.util.ExchangeHelper.extractResultBody(ExchangeHelper.java:695) ~[camel-core-2.19.0.jar:2.19.0]
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.extractResultBody(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:515) ~[camel-core-2.19.0.jar:2.19.0]
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.extractResultBody(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:511) ~[camel-core-2.19.0.jar:2.19.0]
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.requestBodyAndHeaders(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:362) ~[camel-core-2.19.0.jar:2.19.0]
at com.sia.csl.schema.cmservicingpax.services.getpaxrecord.GetPaxRecordService.getVendorResponse(GetPaxRecordService.java:94) [classes/:?]

Caused by: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Unmarshalling Error: Unexpected end of input block; expected an identifier
at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,878852]
at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.unmarshall(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:908) ~[cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb-3.1.11.jar:3.1.11]
at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.unmarshall(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:714) ~[cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb-3.1.11.jar:3.1.11]
at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.io.DataReaderImpl.read(DataReaderImpl.java:179) ~[cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb-3.1.11.jar:3.1.11]
at org.apache.cxf.wsdl.interceptors.DocLiteralInInterceptor.handleMessage(DocLiteralInInterceptor.java:109) ~[cxf-rt-wsdl-3.1.11.jar:3.1.11]
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308) ~[cxf-core-3.1.11.jar:3.1.11]
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.onMessage(ClientImpl.java:780) ~[cxf-core-3.1.11.jar:3.1.11]
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1680) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.11.jar:3.1.11]
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream$1.run(HTTPConduit.java:1176) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.11.jar:3.1.11]
at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.AutomaticWorkQueueImpl$3.run(AutomaticWorkQueueImpl.java:428) ~[cxf-core-3.1.11.jar:3.1.11]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.AutomaticWorkQueueImpl$AWQThreadFactory$1.run(AutomaticWorkQueueImpl.java:353) ~[cxf-core-3.1.11.jar:3.1.11]
```